# Are Windows or custom messages requiring updating pointers exploitable?

Tags: windows, winapi, messaging, exploit

It appears that cross process messages are allowed in Windows, and while Windows appears to have protection so that a lower process can't inject a message to a higher process, say they are at the same level at the time and a message is created with an invalid pointer that gets updated.  Isn't that a potential issue?  For one, crashing apps or corrupting data, or two, maybe exploiting an app that may elevate later?

TIA!!

Comment: If they are already at the same privilege level then they are already inside the airtight hatchway.

Comment: Note: all of the standard messages have very defined protocols to defend against this anyway. So even if an application were to try this it would have to be a custom message which the target would ignore as it wouldn't be expecting it.

Comment: If you have a custom message, then you know the sort of WPARAM/LPARAM to accept.
On common messages, the parameters are well defined. If a same-level process  wants to hack another one, there are easier and more reliable methods anyway.

Comment: Yes you can crash other apps by sending random messages to them. This can't be used for privilege escalation because you can't send messages to higher privileged apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross process security risks are all about using the enhanced privileges of other processes to do something that your process cannot do. Privilege isolation of the message system protects against that.

> crashing apps or corrupting data

Processes can terminate other processes at the same privilege level. Being able to send messages to other processes at the same privilege level adds nothing new.

> exploiting an app that may elevate later

Processes cannot elevate later. Elevation happens as part of process creation.